# Restrict or handle user's asked queries in dialog flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have developed one Agent in DailogFlow. I want to restrict the user to ask any worthless queries to our system.

1). For this purpose, I want our intent will get hit only if the ***user's asked query length*** will be greater than 3 words else we'll simply say *you can't proceed or please ask your question in detail.*

2). We need to add one provision through which we can classify the abusive/defamatory/illegal words from the user's asked queries and stop it then and there.

Please suggest how can we achieve the above 2 items.

Comment: You'd have to do these things in your fulfillment

Comment: I want to put these validations before the user's query matched with any intents.

Comment: Are you building your agent for Google Assistant or any other platform?

Comment: Are you going to intercept a query [input](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput) before triggering specific intent?

Comment: I have build agent for Google Assistant using dialogue Flow. 
And Yes before trigger to any specific intent I want to intercept the query. How to capture the query before trigger any specific intent that's my exact question.

Comment: The best way would be to implement 'middleware' in your webhook.

Comment: I agree with @Nick Felker, it needs to be reconsidered involvement of transitional software that can afford the user query interception and callback. Would it be desired for your intents?